# select statement into function sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, function

I am having trouble turning this select statement into a function that I can use as a computed persisted column. All it is doing is subtracting the previous rows value. I want the computed column to contain the result of the SampleValue subtraction. I do not have that much experience with functions. Should I split up the select statement and try to declare parts of it into variables?

```
select coalesce(a.SampleValue - (select 
b.SampleValue from BM1OILT b where b.Row = a.Row - 1), 
a.SampleValue) AS Usage from dbo.BM1OILT a
```

Any guidance/help would be appreciated. I am using sql server 2008.

Comment: It would appear to need an input parameter so that it only returns one row.

Comment: Don't forget `WITH SCHEMABINDING` on the function.

Comment: You won't be able to mark a column with this function as persisted. I don't know if select to a table is prohibited itself, but the function won't deterministic.

Comment: So, I should just abandon this route of thinking(computed column persisted)? and just use this select statement when I need to pull data from the Usage column.. If I switched the coalesce to an isnull, would that make a difference.. I guess I will only have maybe 50,000 rows, so running this query shouldn't take too long..